# Magento customizing Rating radio button

Tags: php, magento, collections, rating

Want to reverse the value of radio button field :

**Now the default situation in magento :**
1 star => 6
2 star => 7
3 star => 8
4 star => 9
5 star => 10

**Expected customization** : 
5 star => 10
4 star => 9
3 star => 8
2 star => 7
1 star => 6

I tried to put the `arsort` but in vain.

```
Code :
```

Path : Mage/review/Block/Form.php

```
public function getRatings()
    {
        $ratingCollection = Mage::getModel('rating/rating')
            ->getResourceCollection()
            ->addEntityFilter('product')
            ->setPositionOrder()
            ->addRatingPerStoreName(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
            ->setStoreFilter(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
            ->load()
            ->addOptionToItems();
        return $ratingCollection;
    }
```

Path: form.phtml (template file code)

```
<?php foreach ($this->getRatings() as $_rating): ?>
                        <tr>
                            <th><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_rating->getRatingCode()) ?></th>
                        <?php foreach ($_rating->getOptions() as $_option): ?>
                            <td class="value"><input type="radio" name="ratings[<?php echo $_rating->getId() ?>]" id="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_rating->getRatingCode()) ?>_<?php echo $_option->getValue() ?>" value="<?php echo $_option->getId() ?>" class="radio" /></td>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                        </tr>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

The value that comes in radio button : `value="<?php echo $_option->getId() ?>"`
i.e : In ascending order (default) : 11,12,13,14,15
Should come as : 15,14,13,12,11.

Comment: Please post the relevant code

Comment: @billyonecan : Have added the updated part .

Answer (score 0):

there is a PHP function array_reverse() to reverse the array of the ratings.
This will be your final result:

```
<?php foreach ($this->getRatings() as $_rating): ?>
    <tr>
        <th><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_rating->getRatingCode()) ?></th>
        <?php foreach (array_reverse($_rating->getOptions()) as $_option): ?>
            <td class="value"><input type="radio" name="ratings[<?php echo $_rating->getId() ?>]" id="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_rating->getRatingCode()) ?>_<?php echo $_option->getValue() ?>" value="<?php echo $_option->getId() ?>" class="radio" /></td>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

I've also tried and does the job.